# How do I communicate with an IronPython component in a C#/XNA game?

Tags: xna, c#, component-based, python, scripting

My XNA game is [component-oriented](http://cowboyprogramming.com/2007/01/05/evolve-your-heirachy/), and has various components for position, physics representation, rendering, etc, all of which extend a base `Component` class. The player and enemies also have **controllers** which are currently defined in C#. I'd like to turn them into Python scripts via IronPython (a .NET implementation of Python). My problem is that I'm not sure how to interact with those scripts.

The examples in [Embedding IronPython in a C# Application](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/53611/Embedding-IronPython-in-a-C-Application) suggest I'd have to create something like a Script component which compiles a Python script and calls the controller's Update method via Python - essentially, it'd be a wrapper class for C# to interface with Python.

I feel that I'm missing something in my research. There *must* be a way to load up a script, instantiate a Python object (either in the Python script or in C#) and then then have a *direct* reference to that Python object in my C# code.

**Is there a way to work with an IronPython object *directly*, or is a wrapper required?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've figured out how to do this. As I expected, since IronPython compiles down to CLR, C# and IronPython objects can interact with each other just fine with no special treatment necessary. I've created a script which actually creates a new type of Component which can be referenced just fine from C#.

**A brief word on my game's structure:** Its solution has two projects: Game, and GameEngine. The Game is what is ultimately compiled into an EXE, and the GameEngine is compiled into a DLL which sits in the same directory.

#### The script

This currently sits in the default content project, has no build action and is copied to the output directory.

Note that the Component class is a part of GameEngine, and so is compiled into *GameEngine.dll*. It also has nothing to do with XNA's GameComponent class and its methods don't need to be passed a GameTime object.

```
import clr
clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath("GameEngine.dll")
from GameEngine import *
# or: from GameEngine import Component

class PyComponent(Component):
    def __new__(self):
        Component.__new__(self)

    def Initialize(self):
        pass

    def Update(self):
        pass

    def Draw(self):
        pass

pc = PyComponent()
```

#### How the script is compiled and run

Just once within the game, I run this:

```
// Engine setup stuff. The scope can work with variables in the script by
// adding references, accessing/removing current references, etc.
// Each script COULD have its own scope but I have no reason to do that yet.
ScriptEngine PythonEngine = Python.CreateEngine();
ScriptScope DefaultScope = PythonEngine.CreateScope();

string filename = @"Content\ScriptTest.py";
ScriptSource script = PythonEngine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile(filename, Encoding.ASCII);
script.Execute(scope);
```

When the script gets executed, it creates its own instance of a PyComponent.

Of course you'll need to reference the IronPython library and the Microsoft Dynamic runtime. I've found I only need these four DLLs from the root folder of the IronPython download:

- IronPython.dll
- IronPython.Modules.dll
- Microsoft.Dynamic.dll
- Microsoft.Scripting.dll

Add these references to your project, then these `using` statements to your code (according to [Embedding IronPython in a C# Application](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/53611/Embedding-IronPython-in-a-C-Application)):

```
using IronPython.Hosting;
using IronPython.Runtime;
using Microsoft.Scripting;
using Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting;
```

#### Obtaining a reference to the Python object

I'm not sure how I'd get a reference directly from the script, but I do have a roundabout way of doing that. In my engine design, all components automatically register themselves with the engine's component collection, so I can get a reference to the object through there. In a more specific case, you could just have new Python objects register themselves with a queue somewhere, so you create them and then immediately retrieve them.

Comment: My last update to this post will be when I figure out how to directly obtain a reference to the python object.